# how can I get the tobot pose with real-map?

Tags: ros, localization, navigation, ros-kinetic, hector-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm using ROS kinic with Ubuntu-16.04

In the case of the Gazebo environment 'gazebo model topics' are published and I just adopt and use that.

Recently I made a little map using the g_mapping package and tested `amcl_node` to get its pose data in realtime.

It was certainly possible but the subscription frequency was rather slow; I want a pose data which is published as fast as `/odom` topic is.

I also tried `hector_slam` module, but because it doesn't use real map data which is made before a real run, the published pose data has rather low reliability.

Would you please happen to recommand me the appropriate localization package?

I had a feeling that `amcl_node` without navigation algorithm might have worked, but it didn't, unfortunately.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/362688/how-can-i-get-the-tobot-pose-with-real-map?/) by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2020-10-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think, in general, the odom->base_link transform is published pretty fast, but the map->odom transform is in general always published much slower (see [REP-105 Coordinate Frames For Mobile Platforms](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html) for a breakdown of the frame conventions if you are unsure).

The reason for this is that data sources that can provide globally (read: map) referenced information like a laser scanner (read: amcl) or GPS (read: [navsat_transform_node](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/robot_localization/html/navsat_transform_node.html)) generate data at a much slower rate.

Wheel encoders and IMUs, which are generally used for the odom->base_link transform generally produce data much more quickly and therefore can produce the transform much faster. So in general, it will not be possible to get a globally corrected map->odom transform as fast as you get odom->base_link.

Read Tom Moore's answer to this question [robot_localization dual-EKF:How the two ekf nodes work together](https://answers.ros.org/question/318328/robot_localization-dual-ekfhow-the-two-ekf-nodes-work-together/) for more context.

---

Originally posted by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) with karma: 977 on 2020-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2020-10-11**:
@kane_choigo did you find a answer to your question?